# How to hide alt tag output on page?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

Please check the screenshot, let me know how to fix this issue...And you can see there's no image alt data in HTML.
Another thing is that if I use PHP in img src so I can't set width & height like (300 x 300). The output is a full-size image and if I use a static URL in img it works fine, how to deal with that?

```
<nav id="nav-single">
    <?php
        $prev_post = get_previous_post(); 
        $id = $prev_post->ID ;
        $permalink = get_permalink( $id );
        $thumbnail =  get_the_post_thumbnail( $id );
        $image_alt = get_post_meta($thumbnail, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);   
    ?>
    
    <div class="pexel-previous-post-data">
     
    <div class="pexel-previous-post-img">
        <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" width="300" height="300">
        </a>    
    </div>
    
    <div class="pexel-previous-post-Text">
         <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?> 
            <h5 class="pxl_head--h5"><a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></a>             </h5>
         </span>
    </div>

   </div>   
      
</nav>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your `<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>` is printing the whole `<img ...` tag for the thumbnail. You probably need to change it's properties wherever `get_the_post_thumbnail()` is defined. Or see what happens when you replace the `<img src...` you wrote with just the echo function.

Comment: thanks for your help....it works...
it should be like this...... $thumbnail =  get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` to get post image url as `get_the_post_thumbnail()` returns html with `img` tag. `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` will return only image url.

```
 $thumbnail =  get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id );
```